# sed command to replace and write

Tags: linux, sed, string, json

I am trying to replace the following string with another one from a file which contains few lines.

```
"schema" : "AAAAA",
```

TO

```
"schema" : "BBBBB",
```

Currently, I am doing the following command to get the corresponding line with "schema"

**currentSchema=`cat test.json | grep schema | awk {'print $3'}`**

It will give me the value "AAAAA",

I would like to replace AAAAA with BBBBB

I used the following command

```
sed -e 's/$currentSchema/BBBBB/p' test.json
```

However, it is not able to replace in the same file.

Comment: Add an `-i` switch to the sed command to edit the file in place.

Comment: Consider using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead to perform operations on JSON files. It's a better tool, since it understands the actual underlying format, so it's able to do a better job on it than awk and sed.

Comment: really? how jq can replace the strings?

Comment: `$currentSchema` does not expand within strong/single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "host": "myhost",
    "schema": "AAAAA",
    "lunch": "sandwich"
  },
  {
    "host": "myotherhost",
    "schema": "QQQQQ",
    "lunch": "pizza"
  }
]
```

We'd like to replace each `schema` that is `AAAAA` with `BBBBB`.  We can do this with `jq`:

```
$ jq 'map(if .schema == "AAAAA" then .schema = "BBBBB" else . end)' file.json
[
  {
    "host": "myhost",
    "schema": "BBBBB",
    "lunch": "sandwhich"
  },
  {
    "host": "myotherhost",
    "schema": "QQQQQ",
    "lunch": "pizza"
  }
]
```

If it doesn't matter what the old schema was:

```
$ jq 'map(.schema = "BBBBB")' file.json
[
  {
    "host": "myhost",
    "schema": "BBBBB",
    "lunch": "sandwhich"
  },
  {
    "host": "myotherhost",
    "schema": "BBBBB",
    "lunch": "pizza"
  }
]
```

Since `jq` is a proper JSON parser, this would work even if the file was presented in a more compact form, for example as the single line

```
[{"host":"myhost","schema":"AAAAA","lunch":"sandwhich"},{"host":"myotherhost","schema":"QQQQQ","lunch":"pizza"}]
```

---

For the *actual* problem ([in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475864/sed-command-to-replace-and-write/475881#comment869482_475881)), which is to find the element in `.rules.behavior[]` that has a `.name` key with value `mPulse` and then to change that element's `.options.apiKey` to some other value:

```
jq '.rules.behaviors = [.rules.behaviors[]|select(.name == "mPulse").options.apiKey = "XXX"]' file.json
```

That is, rewrite the `.rules.behaviour` array in such a way that the element whose `.name` key is `mPulse` gets a new `.options.apiKey`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of optimizations, not least of which is eschewing a "useless use of `cat`".  You don't need to `cat file | grep pattern`; you can just `grep pattern file`.  And since you're `grep`ping into `awk`, that can be simplified too:

```
currentSchema="$( cat test.json | grep schema | awk '{print $3}' )"
```

becomes

```
currentSchema="$( awk '/schema/ {print $3}' test.json )"
```

Now, for your `sed` script.  You are using *Strong Quotes* (`'`) around your sed command, which means your shell variables will not be parsed.  You need to use *Weak Quotes* (`"`) for this to work:

```
currentSchema="$( awk '/schema/ {print $3}' test.json )"
sed --in-place "s/$currentSchema/BBBBB/" test.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization steps! I tried the second command but it is giving the following error
sed --in-place "s/$currentSchema/BBBBB" rex.json

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command

Comment: You need a final `/` after the replacement.  `s/new/old/`.

Comment: rex.json contains
"schema" : "AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA",

currentSchema="$( awk '/schema/ {print $3}' rex.json )"
sed --in-place 's/$currentSchema/BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB/' rex.json

But nothing has been changed in rex.json file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep`, `awk`, and `sed` for this; `awk` can do all the task (untested):

```
awk '/schema/ {$3 = "BBBBB"} 1' test.json > /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ test.json
```

Please try and report back.

Comment: That will change the entire `.json` file to _only_ the newly-changed line, discarding the rest of the contents.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Not sure I understand?

Comment: awk '/schema/ {$3 = "BBBBB"} 1' rex.json > /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ yy.json
But yy.json contains the same AAAAA itself.. did not change. Where rex.json contains "AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA",

Comment: oops... please excuse.. let me update the contents in rex.json

Comment: currently, rex.json contains 
"schema" : "AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA",
I tried the following command
awk '/schema/ {$3 = "BBBBB"} 1' rex.json > /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ yy.json
Now yy.json has 
"schema" : BBBBB
Almost there... I need to keep double-quotes there itself along with comma. Basically the entire line should be same.

Comment: Try `awk '/schema/ {sub ("AAAA", "BBBBB", $3)} 1' test.json`, then.

Comment: #!/bin/bash


currentSchema="$( awk '/schema/ {print $3}' rex.json )"


awk '/schema/ {sub ($currentSchema, "BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB", $3)} 1' rex.json > /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ yy.json

still yy.json is not updating